# Dynamically assign array to value of a variable. Eval?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm using Bash 4.

I'm trying out a few experiments with Bash.
I want to dynamically assign an array to the value of a variable. If you read the code below, it will be easier to understand.

```
myFunc =RESULT_PREF 'bar' 'baz'

function myFunc() {
    local params
    parser params "$@"
}


function parser() {
    if [ '=' = "${2::1}" ]; then
        local name="${1}"
        shift 2
        local param_array=( "$@" )

        # In PHP, I'd do:
        # $$name = $param_array

        # The ideal outcome:
        # $params should contain the values 'bar' and 'baz'.
    fi
}
```

How do I do what I've mentioned in the comments of my code?
I can't seem to do this using eval. Even if I could, I've read so many bad things about eval.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you saying that you want one function to assign to a local variable in another function?  I believe that's impossible.  Also, you should get into the habit of saying `"$@"` instead of plain `$@`.  Also, you don't need to quote `'bar'` and `'baz'`, but, as long as you are doing so, you should probably quote `=RESULT_PREF`, too, to make it clear that you're treating it as just a string parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myFunc(){
    parse "$1" &&                          #parse() is a test
    eval "  shift                          #$1 is a valid, eval-safe name
            local name$1 ${1#=}="'("$@")'  #$1 is expanded before shift
}

parse()
    case ${1#=} in
    ("$1"|""|[0-9]*|*[!_[:alnum:]]*) ! :   #return false for all invalid names
    esac
```

It does also work without `eval` given another execution step or two:

```
myFunc(){
    local -a "name$1[@]" "${1#=}"='("${@:2}")' &&
    [ -z "${1%=*}" ] && printf %s\\n "${!name}"
}
```

In that case I just allow the `local` builtin to do all of the validation and assignment at once. Basically, if the `local` command can assign `"${1#=}"=("${@#"$1"}")` successfully *and* `"${1%=*}"` is null then you know the assignment has taken place successfully. Any syntax error - such as bad shell names - will automatically fail and `return` with error during the `local` assignment, and the simple validation `[` test `]` which follows is all that is necessary to ensure that you don't accidentally do `local name=morename=("${@#"$1"}")`.

The natural upshot to this is that when a bad name *is* passed in as `=$1` the shell will automatically print out a meaningful error message to stderr for you and do all of the error handling automatically with no fuss.

Like this:

```
myFunc =goodname 1 2 3 'and some     ;more' &&
myFunc =bad-name 1 2 3 'and some     ;more'
```

---

```
1
2
3
and some     ;more
bash: local: `bad-name=("${@:2}")': not a valid identifier
```

---

Note that doing `function`*`name`*`(){`*`list`*`;}` is almost definitely not what you mean to do.

If you intend to localize the function's traps and similar you need `function`*`name`*`{`*`list`*`;}`.

If you intend to share all state but your `local`ly defined variables with the current shell then `function`*`name`*`(){`*`list`*`;}` or *`name`*`()`*`list`* are equivalent because the `function` keyword is ignored by the shell *(except that some shells which implement it tend to parse the following **`list`** incorrectly if it is not contained in curly braces)* when *`name`* is followed by `()`.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know `local` could do some sort of validation, as well.
`parse()` will be a function stored in a separate shell file that will be sourced in to any script where a function will need it, so I want to keep most of the grunt work within parse. This is all a part of my little experiment :) I'm still learning the finer points of Bash. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: sure, i guess, but it will get messy. when you give a function jurisdiction over another namespace it can tend to get messy. it's why i recommend the `case` statement - it makes more sense to me to use functions as *tests* and allow their returns to direct my handling of namespaces. theres another way, too, with `getopts`.

Answer (score 3):

In bash 4.3+, there is a way to define a variable reference which you can see in `help declare`:

> **-n**: make NAME a reference to the variable named by its value

Therefore a script like this outputs a line `a`:

```
n(){ declare -n g="$1"; g=a; }
n b; printf '%s\n' "$b";
```

So here's how you should do that in `parser`:

```
parser() {
    [ "$1" ] || ! echo 'no name given' >&2 || return 42
    if [[ "$2" == =* ]]; then
        declare -n name="$1"
        shift 2
        name=("$@")
    fi
}
```

Using `eval` does work, but it can be unsafe if you expand the rhs too early:

```
shopt -e extglob # bash >= 3
[[ "$1" == [[:alpha:]_]*([[:word:]]) ]] || return 42 # invalid varname
# mikeserv has another solution for filtering, basically expanding
# the inverse of the expression to basic, portable globs
# Do this:
eval "$1"'=( "$@" )'
eval "$foo=\$bar"
# But not:
eval "$1=(\"$@\")"
eval "$foo=$bar"
```

I think you will know what to do with `eval` then. But simply for a higher possibility that you will accept my answer, let me write it in full:

```
shopt -s extglob
parser() {
    [[ "$1" == [[:alpha:]_]*([[:word:]]) ]] || ! echo 'bad varname' >&2 || return 42
    if [[ "$2" == =* ]]; then
        name="$1"
        shift 2
        eval "$name=(\"\$@\")"
    fi
}
```

Comment: Sounds interesting, but that must be a very recent addition.  It's not in bash version 4.2.37, and I can't find it in the online man pages.

Comment: @G-Man Oh, yes, it seems to be bash 4.3. However it is in the man page: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters talks about the *nameref*.

Comment: @mikeserv Oops, I shouldn't use that `!`.

Comment: @mikeserv Now it matches `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*`.

Comment: and now you still have to handle the initial `=`.

Comment: @mikeserv If you look at the parser invocation carefully, ..

Comment: @mikeserv For future expansion and based on guessing the asker's intent, I should keep parser like this.

Comment: @mikeserv Given that arrays are used here, POSIX-compatibility is disabled in my emit-shell-from-IL procedure.

Comment: @Arthur2e5 - i dunno what that means. but it was just advice - obviously it doesn't work here, since the asker wants to name the array. `dash` does do arrays, though - it does one per function. its a different kind of programming - instead of saving results, you just only generate them when theyre needed at all. its like... just doing instead of preparing to do.

Comment: @mikeserv That's not an array *variable*. It's only argv[], or *positional parameter.

Comment: @Arthur2e5 - its an array.